Odoo17 Add Portal Menu
In Odoo17 i want to add custom Menue in My Account Section where i want to display list and form of my custom modeule enquiry
i try
in my custom wb_portal where i try to add menue Enquiry but this menue is not added please help`your text
<odoo>
<template id="portal_my_home_inherit" inherit_id="portal.portal_layout">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('row')]" position="inside">
            <t t-call="portal.portal_docs_entry">
                <t t-set="url">/my/enquiry</t>
                <t t-set="title">Enquiry</t>
            </t>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>


did you find a solution? having the same problem and the top comment does not solve it

You should check out line 11 of addons/hr_timesheet/views/hr_timesheet_portal_templates (on Odoo Github). Its a pretty good copy-pastable example on how to throw a button onto the portal.
Because you didn't really mention what else you have done code-wise, you'd probably have to implement a odoo.http.Controller to render a template for your "/my/enquiry" route.
